# Rigid body bursting and clustering

Tags: rigidbody

I'm trying to make a logo animation of it crashing down to cubes.
Even though I followed a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XNDO2xvUHtc), I have a different result.....

1st problem: I copied the left side of M to the right so it should behave in the same way, but while the left side breaks down into cube, the right side clusters.

2nd problem: In the tutorial, the big cube falls as a whole and breaks down when it hits the floor, but mine just bursts out from the beginning.

3rd problem: Cubes are jiggling on the floor... and I cannot figure out why.

The file is attached below.

Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qYWe-CjENKWaHYKSOzEiJVqmotvhu_1O/view?usp=sharing

[image]
[image]

Comment: Blender File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qYWe-CjENKWaHYKSOzEiJVqmotvhu_1O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, for future reference, all supplemental information should be in the body of your question rather than in the comments. Reason being is that comments are considered disposable, are not searchable, and there are users that will not even read them.

Answer (score 1):

Your cubes are sticked to each other, so you must be sure that the *Sensitivity > Margin* is at 0. So give *Margin* > 0 to one of the cubes, select all the cube, select the one with 0 at the end to make it active, go into the header menu > *Object > Rigid Body > Copy From Active* and it will work:

[image]